# Using count() to output total entries per month as well as the month

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have tried a bit of searching, and as a result found the count() function to get me closer to my goal, but have stopped a bit. Here's what my code looks like now:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT( * ) as Count
FROM AttendanceDB
WHERE YEAR( class_time ) =  '2015'
AND studentid = '$studentid'
AND furikae = 0
GROUP BY MONTH( class_time )";
```

Then I use `echo $row['Count'];` to output the data.

This allows me to total the number of rows per month for the year of 2015 and then output the answer. Now what I want to do is output the month in each row along with the total. I could just preformat everything, but there are some studentids which have entries beginning partway through the year, which means that the first months don't output any results.

How can I SELECT both the month from the DB as well as use the count function at the same time? Thanks

Comment: table ddl, sample input and desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I think will help you:

```
$sql = "SELECT MONTH( class_time ) AS month, COUNT( * ) as Count
FROM AttendanceDB
WHERE YEAR( class_time ) =  '2015'
AND studentid = '$studentid'
AND furikae = 0
GROUP BY MONTH( class_time )";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works perfectly. Seems simple now that it's staring me in the face. Is the a simple way to output the month using the calendar names rather than numbers? Using the date function perhaps?

Comment: I am glad this answer helped you, so can you check it as the right answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an agregator function

```js
$sql = "SELECT COUNT( * ),max(YOUR MONTH COLUMN) as MONTH as Count
FROM AttendanceDB
WHERE YEAR( class_time ) =  '2015'
AND studentid = '$studentid'
AND furikae = 0
GROUP BY MONTH( class_time )";
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$sql = "SELECT MONTH(class_time) AS m, COUNT(*) AS c
    FROM AttendanceDB WHERE YEAR(class_time) = '2015'
    AND studentid = '$studentid'
    AND furikae = 0
    GROUP BY m";
```

This way you'll have the month as a separate column, which will also show in the result as `$row['m']` and the count per month as `$row['c']`. (I avoid the same names as the MySQL function names, hence the `m` and `c`.)